# Usuário sem acesso a recursos mapeados no Security-role do web.xml

Tags: java, java-ee, jsp

Qual é o comportamento da `security-role` do `web.xml` quando o usuário não tem permissão de acesso aos recursos do projeto?

É default o weblogic retornar um 404?

Esse status é configurável?

Existe a possibilidade de quando a security identificar que o usuário não tem permissão de acesso ao recurso, realizar um redirect para outra página?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Os servidores de aplicação retornam 401 (Not Authenticated) quando o usuário não está autenticado e redirecionam para a página de autenticação, se estiver configurado no web.xml.

Quando o usuário não possui o papel necessário para o recurso, é devolvido código de retorno 403 (Proibido - Forbidden).

Caso queira personalizar o código de retorno, ou a página a ser exibida, você terá de tratar isso programáticamente.

```
boolean HttpServletRequest.isUserInRole(String role)
```

O objeto HttpServletRequest pode ser consultado. À partir da resposta você poderá decidir que código de retorno ou página será exibida.